# SpringSecurity - Concurrent Session does not work

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am implementing the  control of concurrent session by  Spring Security.

But when I login in the system by a Chrome with a User and after on the FireFox with the same User, does not display the error message. Also I get no exception in my console.

my web.xml :

```
<!-- ... -->

<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- .... -->
```

my security.xml :

```
  <-- .... -->

   <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?logout=true" 
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>


    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler"/>


    <security:custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"/>
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="concurrentSessionManager" session-authentication-error-url="/login?msg=SessionError"/>


</security:http>


<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="concurrentSessionManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Authentication Manager -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Custom Authentication provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="hemisphereAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />  


<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/login?msg=SessionError" />
</bean> 

<bean id="concurrentSessionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1"/>
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="hemisphereAuthenticationProvider" class="security.HemisphereAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="security.HemisphereAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="no" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="security.HemisphereAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>

<bean id="logoutHandler" class="security.HemisphereLogoutHandler"/>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: If I see it correctly, you use stock components provided by Spring Security to implement the concurrent session management. In that case why don't use the simpler namespace configuration instead of manually wiring the beans? That would be less error prone. I guess the settings you made on the beans are also exposed by the [namespace elements](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-session-management).

Comment: Can you give me an example? Or show me where have an example?

Comment: Try the Spring Security "tutorial" sample, the reference manual, or there are lots of examples on SO.

Comment: I tried that way, but still the same thing:    
  <security:session-management> 
     <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/> 
  </security:session-management>

Comment: Start from the sample application itself, which should work. Then add the extra stuff you want.

Comment: @walterazevedo Hi, I am facing same problem, did you found solution to above problem?